# Simple Adjustment of Payments based on Gender Distribution, Easy Fix?

Tags: r, dplyr, normalization, survey

I would like to graph gender disparities in payments over time and would like to adjust them by the ratio of men to women.  Here is a header for my dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 3,928 x 3
# Groups:   gender [2]
   Date_of_Payment gender Daily_Total
   <date>          <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2013-08-01      female      23718.
 2 2013-08-01      male       151540 
 3 2013-08-02      female      16650.
 4 2013-08-02      male        31833.
 5 2013-08-03      female        147.
 6 2013-08-03      male         3074.
 7 2013-08-04      female        186.
 8 2013-08-04      male          954.
 9 2013-08-05      female      28451 
10 2013-08-05      male        65211.
```

Assuming 59% of recipients were male and 41% were female, how do I adjust the Daily_Total to reflect that discrepancy?

Would as simple adjustment by relative distribution suffice? Survey package? Thanks for any help!

**** UPDATE ****

Ok so based on feedback from stefan, here's the code as it stands:

```
> df_gender %>% 
+   group_by(Date_of_Payment, gender, .drop = FALSE) %>%
+   summarize(Daily_Total= sum(Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars)) %>%
+   group_by(gender) %>%
+   mutate(adjusted_total = case_when(
+     gender == "female" ~ Daily_Total / 0.41, 
+     gender == "male" ~ Daily_Total / 0.59)) %>% 
+   mutate(adjusted_total = adjusted_total/2)
# A tibble: 3,928 x 4
# Groups:   gender [2]
   Date_of_Payment gender Daily_Total adjusted_total
   <date>          <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 2013-08-01      female      23718.         28924.
 2 2013-08-01      male       151540         128424.
 3 2013-08-02      female      16650.         20304.
 4 2013-08-02      male        31833.         26977.
 5 2013-08-03      female        147.           179.
 6 2013-08-03      male         3074.          2605.
 7 2013-08-04      female        186.           227.
 8 2013-08-04      male          954.           809.
 9 2013-08-05      female      28451          34696.
10 2013-08-05      male        65211.         55263.
# … with 3,918 more rows
```

I divided by 2 at the end to bring the numbers back down.

Does this look methodologically sound?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you wanna do. Do you have any data of this discrepancy?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I want to see IF there is a gender disparity.  I already know there are more men than women in the field and if I graph Daily_Total there is a clear disparity in payments. However - that may be just due to disparity in numbers (which we already know about) as opposed to disparity in action (which would require normalizing payments by gender somehow)

Comment: If you have the numbers of females and males then one option is to compare payments per capita. If you got only the percentage shares then dividing by shares gives you a kind of standardized total payments. Both measures would reflect the disparity in payments.

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes. Alt least to me this methodologically sound. Because the disparity in the adjusted payments now reflects the gender disparity after taking account of the disparity related to the differing number of females and males.